# How do i raise my variable by 1 with a press of a button (python)?

Tags: python, variables

I want to make a counter that starts with 0 and each click will raise this number by 1, but i doesn't change why?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

number_count= 0

def myClick():
  (number_count) + 1



myLabel = Label(text= number_count)
myLabel.pack()



myButton = Button(root, text="+1", padx=50, pady=50, command=myClick)
myButton.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First `global number_count` then `number_count += ` inside the function. However this will not update the label with the new numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `def myClick():`

- declare the 'number_count' variable as global
- use the 'config()' function to change the label

Here's the rectified code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

number_count= 0

def myClick():
    global number_count
    number_count += 1
    myLabel.config(text = number_count)

myLabel = Label(text= number_count)
myLabel.pack()

myButton = Button(root, text="+1", padx=50, pady=50, command=myClick)

myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Pack, Button


root = Tk()

number_count = 0

def myClick():
  global number_count
  number_count += 1
  myLabel.configure(text=number_count)

myLabel = Label(text=number_count)
myLabel.pack()

myButton = Button(root, text="+1", padx=50, pady=50, command=myClick)
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You don't configure the label so it didn't change, also you should always use in such cases += for example. Also you have to global number_count so it's available everywhere